# How To Know Last Item of FlatList

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a FlatList.

I want to add comma between items.

Currently working like this;

If there is only one item;
`Mon,`

If there are multiple items;
`Mon, Tue, Wed,`

My code;

```
<FlatList
  data={job.schedule}
  renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
    <View style={[[Layout.center], {}]}>
      <Text style={[[Fonts.textInterRegular12]]}>
        {item.dayHuman.slice(0, 3)}{', '}
      </Text>
    </View>
  )}
  horizontal
  keyExtractor={item => item.id}
  extraData={this.state}
  showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
/>
```

Above code has two issues.

If there is only one item, I don't want to add a comma.
E.g. `Mon`

If there are multiple items, I don't want to add a comma next to the last item.
E.g. `Mon, Tue, Wed`

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When working with ReactNative [FlatList](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist), you can use FlatList's `ItemSeparatorComponent` prop to render a component between each item, but not at the start or end of the list.

You can use FlatList's `ListFooterComponent` & `ListHeaderComponent` props to render some JSX or a component at the end or start of the list.

See diagram below.

---

If the above doesn't help and you just need to know that you are at the end of the list within a `renderItem`, you can check the `index` in the metadata provided to `renderItem` against the length of `data`.

```
const data = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday'];

export default function App() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
    <FlatList
      data={data}
      renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
        const isEnd = index === data.length - 1;

        return (
          <View>
            <Text>
              {item}{isEnd && <Text>. </Text>}
            </Text>
          </View>
        );
      }}
      horizontal
      keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
      extraData={this.state}
      showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
      ItemSeparatorComponent={() => <Text>, </Text>}
      ListFooterComponent={() => <Text>The End!</Text>}
    />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

[Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@ksav/trembling-edamame)

---

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. `isEnd` works perfectly.

Comment: Wow, this is a great answer.  More upvotes!

Answer (score 1):

```
<FlatList
  data={job.schedule}
  renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
    <View style={[[Layout.center], {}]}>
      <Text style={[[Fonts.textInterRegular12]]}>
        {item.dayHuman.slice(0, 3)}
        {index !== job.schedule.length -1 && ', '}
      </Text>
    </View>
  )}
  horizontal
  keyExtractor={item => item.id}
  extraData={this.state}
  showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this

```
<FlatList
      data={job.schedule}
      renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
        <View style={[[Layout.center], {}]}>
          <Text style={[[Fonts.textInterRegular12]]}>
            {item.dayHuman.slice(0, 3)}{index < job.schedule.length -1 ?', ':""}
          </Text>
        </View>
      )}
      horizontal
      keyExtractor={item => item.id}
      extraData={this.state}
      showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
    />
```